# Quasar gutter not working as expected between rows

Tags: html, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am currently trying to create an interface in my app using quasar.

I have the following code in my template in the mainLayout.vue:

```
<q-page-container>
      <q-page>
        <div class="q-gutter-y-sm">
      <div class="row justify-center items-center q-col-gutter-sm" v-for="(row, index) in state.rows" :key="index">
        <div class="column" v-for="(card, cardIndex) in row.cards" :key="cardIndex">
        <q-card class="q-pa-md">
          <q-card-section>
            <q-input v-model="card.title" label="Title" />
            <q-input v-model="card.description" label="Description" />
            <q-input v-model="card.image" label="Image URL" />
            <!-- Add more card content as needed -->
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
              <q-btn push @click="addCard(index)" color="primary" icon="add" round dense />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "row justify-center">
        <q-btn  push @click="addBottomRow" class="q-mt-md justify-center" color="primary" label="Add new row"/>

        </div>
      </div>
      </q-page>
    </q-page-container>
```

The q-gutter-y-sm doesn't seem to apply at all. between the div using the v-for and the div with just the "addBottomRow" button a lot of padding exists, but the rows created by my v-for are right on top of eachother.

q-col-gutter works for all the ones contained in a singular row.

What am I doing wrong to add padding on the top and bottom of each row?